# javascript : create and save files to device

Tags: javascript

this code is working fine when I open it in browser. but when I create application it's showing nothing..!!
please help. how do I create application that saving files

```
<html><body>
  <script src="text/javascript">
  // Function to download data to a file
  function download(data, filename, type) {
    var file = new Blob([data], {type: type});
    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {// IE10+
      window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, filename);
    }
    else { // Others
      var a = document.createElement("a"),
          url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      a.href = url;
      a.download = filename;
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.body.removeChild(a);
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);  
      }, 0); 
    }
  }
  </script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: What kind of application? On what platform?

Comment: What is "my device"? Really, try to be a little more generous with details, please.

Comment: my above code when I open in browser it's showing download dialog and downloads the file.. but if i create application my application is showing nothing... I want my application to show download dialog like browsers to download the file

Comment: That much is clear. What is not clear is what you mean by "application". Are you using this code with electron? React native?

Comment: no iam creating my own app with Html and javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly save the file you create, since that would cause massive security problems, but you can provide it as a download link for the user. You can suggest a file name via the download attribute of the link, in browsers that support the download attribute. As with any other download, the user downloading the file will have the final say on the file name though.

If you want to immediately initiate the download instead of requiring the user to click on a link, you can use mouse events to simulate a mouse click on the link as Lifecube's answer did. I've created an updated example that uses this technique.

```
        var create = document.getElementById('create'),
        textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');
        create.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('download', 'info.txt');
        link.href = makeTextFile(textbox.value);
        document.body.appendChild(link);

          // wait for the link to be added to the document
          window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
          var event = new MouseEvent('click');
          link.dispatchEvent(event);
           document.body.removeChild(link);
         });

          }, false);
```